# In python ctypes, "c_ubyte" existences, but "c_ubyte_p" does not exist

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

The problem has been bothering me for a few days.
I use python call dll Dynamic link library.
This is C++ callback function：

```
typedef void(CALLBACK *fRealDataCallBack)(
  LONG      lRealHandle,
  DWORD     dwDataType,
  BYTE      *pBuffer,
  DWORD     dwBufSize,
  DWORD     dwUser
);
```

I redefined it in python like this:

```
def realdatacallback(lRealHandle, dwDataType, fBuffer, dwBufSize, pUser):
    print("hi")

pRealDataInfoFv = CFUNCTYPE(c_long, c_int, c_char_p, c_int, c_void_p)
pRealDataInfoHandle = pRealDataInfoFv(realdatacallback)
```

There is something wrong with the code.Please look at the third parameter: BYTE *pBuffer.
In ctypes, "c_ubyte" existences, but "c_ubyte_p" does not exist.
How can I fix this?
Finally， I have to say that I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

In ctypes you can use POINTER(c_ubyte)